# modifying IsFilterable of wpf RadGridView programmatically

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview

1. I dont have XAML for columns so that I want to set "IsFilterable" programatically,
2. I have two checkbox columns when checking the check box of first checkbox column automatically the second checkbox column also checked, it should be one way.

can you please guide me how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution:

Here are the way to achieve your requirement.

1. Setting IsFilterable :

You have auto-generated columns based on the data you populate RadGridView with. In order to change the default settings for any of those columns, you can subscribe for the AutoGeneratingColumn event and work with e.Column, then you can able to set the visibility of IsFilterable property.

2. Controlling CheckBox columns:

You should bind both the GridViewCheckBoxColumns to the same or related property from your bound data object. Once the bound property raises a PropertyChanged notification the value in the CheckBox column will be updated.